# Why size of struct in C increases when passed by reference

Tags: c, struct

I have been trying to understand structs and how their sizes differ based on the order members are declared and how padding and alignment are associated with that.

When I declare the struct like the one you see below, I get the size of memory I expected which is 4 bytes.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
} GPS;

int main()
{
   GPS st;
   st.x = 42;
   int size;
   size = sizeof(st);
   printf("\n Size: %d", size);
   return 0;
}
```

But when I pass the struct by reference to a function, the struct increases its size to 8 bytes and I'm not sure why. I read everything about bit alignment and padding but it doesn't seem that has anything with the increase in size.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
} GPS;

int main()
{
   GPS st;
   st.x = 42;
   printStruct(&st);
   return 0;
}

void printStruct(GPS *stptr)
{
    int size;
    char *ch = (char *)stptr;
    size = sizeof(stptr);
    printf("Size: %i \n", size);
}
```

So my question is, why does the struct increase in size when passed by reference?

Comment: One is the size of the struct, the other is the size of a pointer

Comment: `sizeof(stptr)` evaluates to the size of the pointer, not what it points *to*.  Use `sizeof *stptr` instead.

Comment: also, understand there is no pass by reference in C, only pass by value. In this case, `&st` takes the address of `st`, and that pointer is passed to `printStruct`, where a copy is made and stored with `stptr`. Within this function you can dereference that pointer and make changes to the original object, but the `stptr` itself is a copy of the pointer (passed by value) from `main`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size isn't increasing.  You're getting the size of something else.

In your `printStruct` function, `stptr` has type `GPS *`, i.e. a **pointer** to `GPS`.  A pointer to a struct is different from a struct instance, so the sizes don't have to be the same.

Had you used `sizeof(*stptr)`, i.e. the size of what `stptr` points to, you would have gotten the value you expect.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you for that.  I totally confused the two around.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is 8 bytes. When you pass by reference you're actually sending a pointer not the actual struct.